# Looking for a regular expression - parse email

Tags: regex

I need to parse out the email address portion of the following strings:

> "mr. bunny" <bob@bunny.com>
>   <bob@bunny.com>
>   "bob is a bunny" <bob@bunny.com>
>   bob@bunny.com
>   "123 go bob go!" <bob@bunny.com>

In all cases Im looking for the string "bob@bunny.com" and can ignore the rest.

I've tried various combinations of /"[^"]?"?\s?<?([\w@.]?)>?/ but finding the magic pattern is escaping me.

Suggestions?

FWIW this will be running in Perl.

Comment: Does something along the lines of [`(\w+@\w+\.\w+)`](http://regexr.com?30u2b) not suit your requirements?

Comment: what happens if the email address is "bob@bunny.rabbit.com"? ( I realize this is a change to the original question )

Comment: Then you get a little more complicated: [`([a-zA-Z0-9._%-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4})`](http://regexr.com?30u2h). I said "something along the lines of..." because it sounded like you had tried standard email regexes, and they didn't suit your needs.

Comment: Its a great answer either way. Post it as such and I'll mark it as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a simple Regex will do, then you can use:

[([a-zA-Z0-9._%-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+.[a-zA-Z]{2,4})](http://regexr.com/?30u2h)

As @Peter mentioned, it gets much more complicated if you want to comply with RFC 2822. However, in reality you may not want to comply completely, as the RFC specifies the usage of obsolete double quotes and brackets, which aren't even supported by some email applications. A more practical, but still fairly robust, example is something like this:

```
[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want one that abides by RFC 2822 then translating this into Regex syntax would be what you want:

```
(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\])
```

From [http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html](http://bit.ly/JjVZRK) which has other, smaller, expressions.